# Filling A Table Cell With Double Lined Border

Tags: autocad

I don’t know if this is an unavoidable problem with AutoCAD or if its just a setting somewhere, but whenever I try to fill a cell with double lined borders, the image below is the result, which looks horrible. AutoCAD doesn't fill the inner border, but starts filling from the middle of the two lines. I want it to only fill the inner border. I dearly hope its just a setting.

[image: Double line cell filled]

Comment: Are you using .NET, C++ or VBA? And what's the problem (I can see the double-lined borders).

Comment: I am using. NET 3.5, and sorry for not specifying. I updated my question.

Comment: This is most likely related to the table cell style, have you double checked that?

Comment: There's not much you can customise of change in terms of the cell style, unless I am missing something @Augusto?

Comment: I haven't test nor have a sample code, but have you looked at the Cell.Borders.Horizontal.DoubleLineSpacing property?

Comment: You're probably going to have to give up on the double line border. Like in your question, AutoCAD does center the double line on the cell edge. How about just increase the border weight and change its color, then fill the cell background? Good luck @LuiP3rd